# To have two delimiter instead of one in read, bash

Tags: string, bash, stdin

How to have two delimiter instead of only one of char. `/`  as in this, the ':' char. needs to be honored too

```
while read -d':' -d'/' l;do echo $l ;done < file.txt
```

not work, how to solve it ?

Comment: Use IFS and read in an array: `echo "this:is/a poem/hello:cruel world:and bye" | while IFS=:/ read -r -a line; do echo "${line[@]}"; done`. Output: `this is a poem hello cruel world and bye`.

Comment: @Roadowl The only change I would make to the above is `printf '%s\n' "${line[@]}"` to print each item on a separate line as the OP's original code would if it worked.

Comment: Also note that Bash's `read -d` delimiter is a Record Separator which accepts only one single character, and allows to replace the POSIX shell's NewLine Record Separator by any other character, including a null. It should not be confused with the Internal Field Separator, which is defined into the `IFS` environment variable, and accepts multiple characters as delimiters.